# Datatable value not updating when using keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to implement a ctrl+s shortcut so my users can save their changes in the winform app i'm developing. This is the code for the shortcut:

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
 {
  if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
  {
    //Save code
    return true;
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
 }
```

When a user makes a bound checkbox checked I expect the bindingsource that is used for binding to have it's data table updated with this new value.  When I click the save button it shows the data table has the updated value of 1.  When I do ctrl+s the value shows up as 0, so nothing gets saved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered testing the code within the if statement to make sure that it is actually being reached?

Comment: I tried to post this as a comment and not an answer but i cant seem to find the button for commenting on the actual question for some reason.

Comment: Metinoheat,  Thanks for the reply.  Yes I have tested that it goes in but the issue is that the data table doesn't show the correct value like it does when I click on a save button.  The code within the if is identical to the code within the save button.  Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing your code, its hard to guess as to why this is happening then. I have used key-down events to update data-tables without problem before. I would say the best way to figure this out is to set a breakpoint at the beginning of your code within the processcmdkey event and follow it to see exactly what it does while you watch all the locals and check their values step by step. If you could post your //save code or at least portions of it that might also help us to figure it out. Good Luck.